# Chrome is very slow to apply a style sheet when switching in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, google-chrome

I have a piece of javascript to switch a page's stylesheet on a button click.  It works fine and zippy in IE and Firefox but it's very very slow in Chrome.  It takes about 30secs to re-render and that's on my development machine.   The load time is just a few ms.   I've tried this in angularjs using ng-href and binding the style sheet file name to a scope variable with poor results in Chrome.  Then I included jquery and did it this way

```
 var sheetName = "Content/RPNCalc-" + sizes[size] + ".css";
  angular.element("link[rel='stylesheet']").attr("href", sheetName);
```

again that works dandy in IE & FF but takes about 30 secs in Chrome.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: In the end I did it as a directive:

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did this as a directive called "active-sheet"  and manipulated the "disabled" property.  Works in IE FF & Chrome

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" active-sheet="small" href="Content/RPNCalc-small.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" active-sheet="big" href="Content/RPNCalc-big.css" />

link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on("sizeClick", function (_e, _size) {
               element.prop("disabled", _size != attrs.activeSheet);
            });
         }
```